# how to fetch data from drop down menu and display data related to it on the same screen in C# using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating a web page where the user will select one state from drop down menu and accordingly the data related to state selected should be diplayed on the same screen.I want to display related data from the table.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far?? Nothing!, than you can try some tutorials first
[try this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string abc = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

(now selected item is there at abc , do your operations in this function)
}